# How to set a duration between two toast?

Tags: android, toast, duration

I implemented two toast event by `onClick()` and `onTouch()`. I want to see every toast event, but it is two fast.

How can I set a duration between two toast events?
My code is too short, below.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_like:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I love Irene", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.iv_share:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Together Irene", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.iv_photo:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click Irene", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "down Irene", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "up Irene", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: isn't enough to set the length to LENGTH_LONG instead of short?

Comment: but honestly, I'm not really sure about which is your goal, can you specify what you want to obtain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes me smile.

`OnTouch` events are very fast. It will cause many `Toast` to show. Although all Toast are queued up but you will not be able to measure events matched with fired time.

**Instead You can use `Logs` like this.**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("myClass", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("myClass", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");                
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You will get these logs in your Logcat in Android Studio, or press **`alt+6`**

Comment: uhm, unless you cancel them, toasts will just queue up, so you will see them both and the second will be shown after the first finish (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Logs instead of Toasts of such information.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` change to `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.